# How to add dynamic where clause in laravel using php lighthouse for graphql processing

Tags: php, laravel-5, graph, laravel-lighthouse

I have implemented schema for fetching activities from the system and is working perfortly on fetching the whole list. I want to start passing user_id so as to filter based on the user or to filter by top 10 last week activities. My schema is;

The schema for activity.graphql

```
type ActivityActivity {
 id: ID!
 activity: String!
 user: User @belongsTo
 created_at: String!
 updated_at: String
 deleted_at: String
 createdBy: User @belongsTo
 updatedBy: User @belongsTo
 deletedBy: User @belongsTo
}

extend type Mutation {

createActivityActivity(
    id: ID 
    activity: String!
    user_id: Int!
    source_type: String!
    source_id: Int!
): ActivityActivity @create(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")

updateActivityActivity(
        id: ID!  
        activity: String
        user_id: Int 
        source_type: String
        source_id: Int
): ActivityActivity @update(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")

deleteActivityActivity(id: [ID!]!): [ActivityActivity!]! @delete(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")
}

extend type Query {
    activity_activity: [ActivityActivity!]! @paginate(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")
    find_activity_activity(id: Int! @eq): ActivityActivity @find(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")
}

extend type User {
activity: [ActivityActivity!]! @hasMany
}
```

how can I add fetch statements query that have filter or have where clause eg

```
query {
  activity_activity(count: 10) {
     filters{user_id : 10, created_at:2019-01-01}
     data{
       activity
       created_at,
       user{name,email,created_at}
     }  

  }
}
```

or add a where clause to the query eg

```
query {
  activity_activity(count: 10) {
     where{'user_id = 10 AND created_at=2019-01-01'}
     data{
       activity
       created_at,
       user{name,email,created_at}
     }  

  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Suggested Solution is the filter field as follows

```
extend type Query {
  activity_activity(
    activity: String @where(operator: "like"),
    user_id: Int @eq 
): [ActivityActivity!]! @paginate(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")
find_activity_activity(id: Int! @eq): ActivityActivity @find(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")
```

}

I am implementing an ERP and as per system design users should have advanced search that allows them to perform custom filtering eg Not equal(!=), Not in(!), Greater than(>) etc. In current implementation I have no option but to write different filter parameter for each advanced search. Is there a different option?

Comment: Suggested solution is as follows;
extend type Query {
    activity_activity(
        activity: String @where(operator: "like"),
        user_id: Int @eq 
    ): [ActivityActivity!]! @paginate(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")
    find_activity_activity(id: Int! @eq): ActivityActivity @find(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")
 }

Answer (score 0):

How I see it is that you have a couple of options.

The easiest option is to shift to a full text search using Laravel Scout, in Lighthouse this can be used with the `search` directive found in the [docs here](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#search).

Another option which is also fairly use the `whereConstraints` [directive](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#whereconstraints). This directive basically gives you access to define where part of your query. What that method you can do nested wheres with different AND and OR statements like so

```
{
  people(
    filter: {
      where: [
        {
          AND: [
            { column: "age", operator: GT value: 37 }
            { column: "type", value: "Actor" }
            {
              OR: [
                { column: "haircolour", value: "red" }
                { column: "height", operator: GTE, value: 150 }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ) {
    name
  }
```

So to take your example and build it up using this directive would look something like this

```
extend type Query {
    activity_activity(
        where: WhereConstraints @whereConstraints
    ): [ActivityActivity!]! @paginate(model: "Modules\\Activity\\Entities\\Activity")
}

input WhereConstraints {
    column: String
    operator: String = EQ
    value: Mixed
    AND: [WhereConstraints!]
    OR: [WhereConstraints!]
    NOT: [WhereConstraints!]
}

scalar Mixed @scalar(class: "MLL\\GraphQLScalars\\Mixed")
```

You might want to create some enums for column and operator to limit what operations your users can use and what columns they can filter by.